# Counting instances with same value

Tags: javascript

For a project, I need to do some data manipulation in JavaScript.

I need to convert this object:

```
[
        {"source":"stkbl0001","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0003","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0004","target":"stkbl0005"},
        {"source":"stkbl0004","target":"stkbl0005"}
]
```

to this object:

```
[
    {"source":"stkbl0001","target":"stkbl0005","value":1},
    {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005","value":5},
    {"source":"stkbl0003","target":"stkbl0005","value":1},
    {"source":"stkbl0004","target":"stkbl0005","value":2}
]
```

(notice that some elements in the first object are same and new field `value` contains number of repeats)

Basically, I need to detect and count multiple instances, and to create new field `value` that contains number of instances.

How do I do that?

Comment: Create a new array to hold the results.  Loop over the first array and see if the `source` is in the new array.  If it isn't, add it with a `value` of 1; if it is, increment the `value`.

Comment: Is the `target` always going to be the same?

Comment: No, target may get varoius values @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track with an object:

```
var obj = {};
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var item = arr[i],
      key = item.source + '-' + item.target;
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key].value++;
  else {
     obj[key] = item;
     item.value = 1;
  }
}

for (var prop in obj) {
  result.push(obj[prop]);
}
```

In this example, `arr` is assumed to be your original array, and `result` is your resulting array.

`result` will end up being an array of objects that have unique combinations of `source` and `target` properties, and `value` will be the number that those combinations were encountered.